# Regular Expression to remove specific patterns

Tags: java, regex

```
String str=",Name=Tom,Age=23,something=something,roll=1,somethng=55,"
```

I want to remove all those key value pairs from the string whose value is a number.

Now i am doing something like this

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",[^=]*?=([^,]*),");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    String result = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        if (!isNumeric(m.group(1))) {
            result += m.group(0);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

The expected output is

```
",Name=Tom,something=something,"
```

But now i am getting

```
",Name=Tom,,something=something,"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result=str.replaceAll(",[^=]*?=[0-9]+", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

You may try this.

Comment: No need of reluctant quantifier.

Comment: I would use the regular expression `"(^|,)[^,=]+=[0-9]+(?=,|$)"`.  It protects against lack of leading comma, lack of trailing comma, and values like `",name=Tom,publicKey=24abf3ced,other=something,"`, which your regex will make into  `",name=Tomabf3ced,other=something,"`